# How can I make button label dynamic using javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, button

What I want to do is be able to change the text inside of a button by making the text inside an actual variable.

Something like this:

```
<button type=button>status</button>
```

but instead of a string, it's a variable:

```
var status = 'on';
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're trying to assign the text of a button to a variable then it's as simple as following:

```
var buttonText = "click me!";      
document.getElementById("id-of-your-button").innerHTML = buttonText;
```

Comment: or do you want it to "dynamically" change as the variable changes?

Comment: You typed "innner" instead of "inner". Just in case someone else end up copypasting the line.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using jquery, then its a simple task.

suppose you have a button

then you can use jquery to assing its text by using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var status="on";
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myButton").text(val);
});
</script>
```

or you could pure javascript:

```
var status="on";
document.getElementById('myButton').innerHTML=status;
```

Comment: he's asking to put var name as status he doesn't want to change text on button

Answer (score 3):

Guess this helps:

```
    <button id="myButton" type="button" value=""></button>
    <input id="myInputButton" type="button" value=""></button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var status = 'on';
        document.getElementById('myButton').innerHTML = status;
        document.getElementById('myInputButton').value = status;
    </script>
```